# VBA - Click "Download" from html w/ masked button by anchor

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm new to this website and just begun my journey in HTML. My hope is that I can provide to the community as much as I have received lurking in the answers!

I am currently working on automating some navigation on IE using VBA. All has gone to plan with the exception of the following:

There's a "button" I am trying to click...here is the HTML:

```html
<a class="alignLeft nowrap" href="/assistant/newRunReport?parameterId=de9498-1643e6f7969-5tv0">Download</a>
```

In the past, I have simply used the href to navigate directly to the page. However this particular request returns an error page in the browser so that doesn't seem to be an option.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What link are you trying to access? Is it a folder included in your project, or the one from an external server?
From what I understand, you're trying to access the "assistant" folder is this?
The "/" before "assistant" (/ assistant) can affect the location because it indicates the entry in another folder.

Try if the folder is in the project, without a previous "/":

"assistant/newRunReport?parameterId=de9498-1643e6f7969-5tv0"

Comment: Hey Gustavo, thanks for the quick reply.

To be more specific, I am trying to "click" a button on that downloads a csv file from a website. 

Once I click the button "run" which queues the csv file to downloadable ,  a separate window pops up from which I need to click "download." That's href is the only link I see when I inspect the element tied to the button "download." 

Apologies for any confusion and mix up in terminology as I am very new to this.

Comment: Gustavo, thank you for your reply! I was actually able to resolve the issue by paying closer attention to the href text due to your suggestion. 

I had the preceding portion of the link incorrect and therefore had duplicate "/assistant..." in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried a CSS selector of `a[href='/assistant/newRunReport?parameterId=de9498-1643e6f7969-5tv0']`

Which would be

```
.document.querySelector("a[href='/assistant/newRunReport?parameterId=de9498-1643e6f7969-5tv0']").Click
```

If those fail try:

```
.document.querySelector(".alignLeft.nowrap").Click or
```

or

```
.document.querySelector("a.alignLeft.nowrap")
```

[`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is the method of [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/Document) that applies a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). You select an element by its styling.

`a.alignLeft.nowrap`, for example, is `a` tags with className of `alignLeft nowrap`. The `"."` means className. You are not allowed compound names when using `.querySelector` so you add another dot where the space is to get `a.alignLeft.nowrap`.

`.querySelector` returns a single matching item i.e. the first. `.querySelectorAll` will return a `nodeList` of all matching elements which you then traverse the `.Length` of to get to individual items by index.

Comment: Hello QHarr, I have resolved the issue however I would still like to understand your solutions. During my research I came across this method but did not get it to work. Currently I am getting an error saying "invalid or unqualified reference" when entering your proposed code.

Comment: You can't have just .document. You either need IE.document (IE being the variable representing the instance of IE used for the scraping, or you need to execute against an htmldocument variable.

Comment: So IE.document.querySelector  or HTMLDoc.querySelector,  where Dim IE As InternetExplorer and Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument.

Comment: I don't whether you can run this as well to have a look at some CSS questions I have explained before https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/867896

Comment: Got it. Yes I am using IE. I have IE defined as an object "objIE" so ... ObjIE.document...etc. 

I used the code however I get the error 424: object required.

I added a "Wait" command prior to this line just in case it was a loading issue but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: How many items are there on that page with that className? Can you do .querySelector(".alignLeft.nowrap").Click    If there is more than one then find which number it is at and .querySelectorAll(".alignLeft.nowrap")(n).Click  where n is the appropriate index. Sometimes the sytnax is  .querySelectorAll(".alignLeft.nowrap").Item(n).Click

Comment: That particular class is only present in one instance. However "alignLeft nowrap" shows up within the text of another class as "gwt-Label alignLeft nowrap link".

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on what you meant by narrow down CSS with ...("a.alignleft...) Thank you in advance for all your help. I really appreciate this.

Comment: It seems I am still getting the same object error with both commands "objIE.querySelector("a.alignLeft.nowrap").Click" & sans "a". 

I think this may be what you're alluding to but is there a way for me to drill down to that specific instance of "alignleft.nowrap" other than counting the number instances and entering that as the (N) in your example?

Comment: AH , please excuse the ignorance. I literally put the code you instructed and omitted the "document" portion. 

    objIE.Document.querySelector("a.alignLeft.nowrap").Click did the trick.

Can you elaborate as to what the preceding "a" indicates?

Comment: It means elements with a tag. If you look towards the bottom of my answer I mention this. The query I have put in the comments shows you some of the answers I have given where I use CSS selectors. Also, you can learn here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and practice both there and here is quite fun https://flukeout.github.io/

Comment: QHarr Thanks a ton for your time and knowledge. I will certainly look at these resources!

Comment: Not a problem :-)

Comment: Do you have any other practice websites you recommend?

Comment: Anything really! I'm looking to get my hands dirty as much as I can. I'm looking forward to selecting the plates here shortly. haha.

Comment: When you are ready for the big game.... https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/     https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: Great, thank you for sharing this. Once I build enough rep I'll go ahead and jump on. I plan to devote some serious time to this. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again! I've been looking through the resources you provided and have found them very helpful ...thanks again! I was hoping you could clarify something for me. In your original response you linked the keywords "document" and ".queryselector." 

I saw that the keyword "document" is used to access a webpage. Is this through the perspective of VBA only? Or are these general? I'm a bit confused as to what I'm looking at. Are these terms interchangeable between VBA and HTML?

Comment: So you are interacting with the [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) when you scrape a webpage.  VBA has libraries which replicate many  of the methods you find shown in those links. So HTML Object library for example gives you access to querySelector. Late bound "HTMLfile" has an interface that may also offer this. I find those links well documented and a good place to learn more about scraping. You can enter the same terms into MSDN and see what is returns for VBA.

Comment: In my answers I generally try to show the appropriate syntax for VBA but expose OPs to the wider DOM. Does that make sense? Think about libraries in vba like MSXML2.XMLHTTP library

Comment: Thank you. Yes that makes sense! From what perspective are the methods in the links written if VBA has an "equivalent" command?  Would an HTML user be using those commands as written? As to your last comment, I take MSDN would translate the terminology included in the links to the VBA equivalent. Is there a way to access all the functions housed in the "HTML Object Library" for example?

Comment: It depends on the language. Most of those links I think are written from a javascript point of view. It is not usually too difficult to do an internet search for the VBA equivalent syntax especially on SO or MSDN.  If using early binding then when you add a reference to the appropriate library and create an instance of a class e.g. HTMLDocument you will get intellisense showing available methods/properties.  I generally Google the class/object and aim for more reputable links like MSDN.

Comment: MSDN often has C# or VB.net example. SO will have implementations in lots of languages. I frequently look to javascript, java, python and C# in particular to get a feel for what might be possible in VBA. The javascript user would be using as per the examples in the links. I am guessing there were example further down. If not, I can dig some up for you. Remember YouTube is awesome for this stuff.

Comment: I quite like this guy's tutorials https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman/search?query=web+scraping. I used them for beginner regex for example even though in a different language. You learn the limitations and differences through research and some trial and error.

Comment: Thanks QHarr! I was deep in reading here. I'll take it from here as I understand the connection now. It sounds like in order to be fluent with this I will need to obtain familiarity with other languages. Lastly, what is SO? I was able to look up the other ones on google but can't come across this one. Is MSDN something I can access? I was reading it's something like $20K. I may be mistaken.

Comment: MSDN developer network is free. You don't need to be a member to browse the library. SO is Stack Overflow. Any other questions let me know, I have advised as I understand but I am still relatively "green". You will definitely benefit from looking at other languages. Searching MSDN for example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?ral=1&query=DOM

Comment: Not being able to reply in the chatroom is giving me anxiety haha. Thanks for all the help as always.

Comment: And you can ping from anywhere I have commented with @qharr remembering the @